# Python function to tell whether a timestamp is within the range of list of TimeDelta

Tags: python, timestamp

I would like to write a below function and it will check whether a current_time is within any of the sections: A or B or C. In each section, there is a start and end time.

```
is_in_market_hours(current_time: timestamp, open_hours:List[Tuple[Timedelta, Timedelta]]):
    pass 

A: Timedelta('0 days 09:00:00'), Timedelta('0 days 11:00:00')
B: Timedelta('0 days 13:00:00'), Timedelta('0 days 15:00:00')
C: Timedelta('0 days 22:00:00'), Timedelta('0 days 23:00:00')
```

For example, if current_time is 9:15:55am, then it is inside the range of section A . The function will return True.

I would think I need to use the current_time to get the beginning of the current date, then add the Timedelta in each sections. Then I need to a loop to loop through all the tuple to compare.

Am I on the right track ?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to compare a time to a duration. Wouldn't it be more intuitive to check if given current_time is greater equal a certain start *time* and less than a certain end *time*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution with any()

```
   from datetime import datetime, time

   def is_in_market_hours(current_time, *time_ranges):
       return any(current_time > t[0] and current_time < t[1] for t in time_ranges)

   now = datetime.now().time()

   A = (time(9, 0), time(11, 0))
   B = (time(13, 0), time(15, 0))
   C = (time(22, 0), time(23, 0))

   is_in_market_hours(now, A, B, C)
```